# How do I copy string from text file to Java string?

Tags: java, android

I've looked through the other threads on here and can't find anything that works for me. What I need to do is read a text file from the external storage and copy the text to a string in my Java file. After it gets converted I need it to compare that string to one typed in by the user in an Edittext. This is what I have so far and I'm sure there's a lot wrong with it.

```
            try {
                decrypt();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

            final EditText pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin);

        pin.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Vault/data1.txt");
                        String pinkey = pin.getText().toString();

                        if (pinkey.matches("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Type in pin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else {
                            try {
                                decrypt();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                            String key = new String(file.toString());
                            try {
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                                String line;

                                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                    text.append(line);
                                }
                                br.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (file.exists()) {
                            } else {
                                showHelp(null);
                            }

                            if (pinkey.equals(br)) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I should probably use the scroll bar before commenting :p

Anyways, try your try block like this

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String fileAsString = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
```

Not sure if you need a new line separator, but if your comparing it to another file it might be good to get it in a form that represents a file...I'd assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `Scanner` and `File` objects:

```
public String readFile(String path) {
        try {
            Scanner se = new Scanner(new File(path));
            String txt = "";
            while (se.hasNext())
                txt += se.nextLine() + "\n";
            se.close();
            return txt;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

You open a scanner that scans the file, and as long as there is more to read from the file, you append the next line to a string.

This method returns `null` if the file doesn't exist, and an empty string if the file is empty.